# How to play background music in react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, background-music

I really dont know how to play background music in **react native expo** ..
I tried lot to add music .. since Im beginner I couldn't found
please help me

Answer (score 1):

It will work on Android but will not work on iOS with expo. Need to add the following code in the app.json -

```
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
  "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
  "infoPlist": {
    "UIBackgroundModes": [
      "audio"
    ]
  }
},
```

After that, You have to create standalone application of iOS and it will work on standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library it take mp3 from bundle or you can stream: https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player#readme

Comment: Tnx for reply sir

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported yet By Expo APIS

## You can check the current state of this Expo feature request

https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/audio-playback-in-background

Comment: tnx for ur reply sir